# Using mysql JDBC in the OSGi framework

Tags: mysql, jdbc, osgi, osgi-bundle, eclassnotfound

I have a huge problem with getting a connection to a Database within my OSGi Application. I searched for 3 days an couldn't find a good solution. Just not working and old stuff. I'm using Bndtools for creating my Bundles.

Can anyone please help I'am very desperate.

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Your question needs to be a little more directed. Note that the current version of the MySQL java connector JAR is already an OSGi bundle.

Comment: Well, I'am using the newest version of the mysql JConnector 5.1.35 which i assume is already a runnable OSGi Bundle. I can load it into the framework and its shown as Active. When I try to load the driver with "Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();" its throws an exception that the class is not found.

Comment: What a strange way to instantiate a class! What's wrong with the **new** keyword? By using reflection tricks like this, you hide from Bnd(tools) the fact that your code depends on the `com.mysql.jdbc` package, and therefore bnd does not generate an import for that package, and therefore your bundle cannot see it.

Comment: By the way, please put the details of the problem and the error in the actual question. Currently the question reads as "something doesn't work, please tell me how to fix it", which will be quickly closed by the StackOverflow moderators.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'am new here so I try my best to be more specific next time. Can you give me further advice or tell me a link where i can read more about letting bnd generate the import?

Comment: The bnd manual is here: http://bnd.bndtools.org/. Generally you don't need to do anything, because bnd automatically detects the dependencies of your code and generates imports accordingly. The problem is when dependencies are hidden behind reflective class loading, such as `Class.forName`.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Users shouldn't instantiate a JDBC driver at all, nor should they reference the driver directly. I am unsure what that means in the context of OSGi, but I assume there is a normal way to use a JDBC driver from OSGi applications.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Indeed, and the proper OSGi way would be for the driver (or a related bundle) to publish a `DataSourceFactory` service. However using `Class.forName` doesn't successfully avoid the reference to the driver, it merely hides it, so is actually worse than direct instantiation with the `new` keyword.

Comment: Yes I read about the DataSourceFactory service, I couldn't find a good tutorial or description how to Implement a service like this

Comment: You do not have to implement DataSourceFactoryService as there is already implementation for mysql: https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/MySQL+Driver+Adapter If you drop that jar into your container, a DataSourceFactory OSGi service will be registered and you can use it to instantiate your DataSource or Driver.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of this error seems that the package of the class being used is not present in the Import-package directive of the bundle's manifest.mf.

In OSGi environment, each bundle has its own classloader. So, each class will be loaded only once during the application life span. Whenever a class is being used outside of a bundle, the package the class resides in needs to be present in the Export-package attribute of its jar's manifest.mf.
Any client bundle which requires this package/class, should add the entry in its Import-package attribute of its manifest.mf file.

If you are using maven, you can use maven-bundle-plugin. This plugin will take care of generating appropriate manifest import and export headers by scanning the dependencies present in your project's pom.xml.